# Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the GCS object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-gcp

Ok so i have a spring boot application which is i stored many many files in google cloud storage server. Everything is ok but I have an issue when I try to delete any file (which is UI in my thymeleaf temp engine pressing DELETE button) it says Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist). I can upload video file without any issue into my bucket but when i pressing delete button it says above error. Where is my mistake?

**Service Layer**

```
public VideoLesson uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
        log.debug("Start file uploading service");
        VideoLesson inputFile = new VideoLesson();
        String originalFileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        if (originalFileName == null) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Original file name is null");
        }

        Path path = new File(originalFileName).toPath();

        try {
            String contentType = Files.probeContentType(path);
            VideoLessonDto fileDto = dataBucketUtil.uploadVideo(file, originalFileName, contentType);
            if (fileDto != null) {
                inputFile.setName(fileDto.getFileName());
                inputFile.setFileUrl(fileDto.getFileUrl());
                videoLessonRepository.save(inputFile);
                log.debug("File uploaded successfully, file name: {} and url: {}", fileDto.getFileName(), fileDto.getFileUrl());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error occurred while uploading. Error: ", e);
            throw new GCPFileUploadException("Error occurred while uploading");
        }

        log.debug("File details successfully saved in the database");
        return inputFile;
    }
```

**DataBucketUtil.java**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DataBucketUtil {
    @Value("${gcp.config.file}")
    private String gcpConfigFile;
    @Value("${gcp.project.id}")
    private String gcpProjectId;
    @Value("${gcp.bucket.id}")
    private String gcpBucketId;

    public VideoLessonDto uploadVideo(MultipartFile multipartFile, String fileName, String contentType) {
        try {
            log.debug("Start file uploading process on GCS");
            byte[] fileData = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(convertFile(multipartFile));

            InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource(gcpConfigFile).getInputStream();

            StorageOptions options = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(gcpProjectId)
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream)).build();

            Storage storage = options.getService();
            Bucket bucket = storage.get(gcpBucketId, Storage.BucketGetOption.fields());

            RandomString id = new RandomString(6, ThreadLocalRandom.current());
            Blob blob = bucket.create(fileName + checkFileExtension(fileName), fileData, contentType);

            if (blob != null) {
                log.debug("File successfully uploaded to GCS");
                return new VideoLessonDto(blob.getName(), blob.getMediaLink());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("An error occurred while uploading data. Exception: ", e);
            throw new GCPFileUploadException("An error occurred while storing data to GCS");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private File convertFile(MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            if (file.getOriginalFilename() == null) {
                throw new BadRequestException("Original file name is null");
            }
            File convertedFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(convertedFile);
            outputStream.write(file.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
            log.debug("Converting multipart file : {}", convertedFile);
            return convertedFile;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new FileWriteException("An error has occurred while converting the file");
        }
    }

    private String checkFileExtension(String fileName) {
        if (fileName != null && fileName.contains(".")) {
            String extension = ".mp4";
            log.debug("Accepted file type : {}", extension);
            return extension;
        }

        log.error("Not a permitted file type");
        throw new InvalidFileTypeException("Not a permitted file type");
    }
}
```

**Controller Layer**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/video_lesson/upload")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
        String message;
        try {
            videoLessonService.uploadFile(file);
            message = "Video bazaya müvəfəqiyyətlə yükləndi: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
            model.addAttribute("message", message);
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = "Diqqət bir video seçməlisiniz!";
            model.addAttribute("message", message);
        }
        return "redirect:/video_lesson/files";
    }
```

**And this is the error output**

`Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).`

I tried in my bucket full access in the permissions, in GRANT ACCESS section but same error occurred

Comment: 2 Things: Are you sure of the blob path? Did you double check the path manually? AND Are you running your app on Google Cloud?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere no my application isn't in microservice architect. And I have a many many memory capabilities (for example 500 mb) video file and I stored in mysql db only the video url's which is gcs randomly given me

Comment: Sorry, it was not my questions! When you try to delete a bLOB in GCS, you provide the full path name of that blob to Storage service to delete it. Did you log that blob path to check if it exist in your bucket. In addition, is your springboot application (microservice or monolith, no difference) run on Google Cloud (serverless, VM, GKE,...) or not?